# Is it possible to use 'if - else - elseif' in that order?

Tags: c#, if-statement

If possible I need to use some code where an 'if' follows after an 'else' as follows:

```
if (Car1.isEmpty)
{
    Do stuff
}
else 
{
    Car1.EmptyOut();
}
else if (Car2.isEmpty)
{
    Do stuff
}
else
{
    Car2.EmptyOut()
}
```

Etcetera. This needs to be done multiple times. Basically if Car1 isn't available (because it's not empty), Car2 needs to be used and Car1 needs to be send home to get emptied.

I'm wondering if it will get to the next 'else-if' statement though.

Comment: That is not syntactically correct.

Comment: read some basic c# tutorial :)

Comment: Why not start the next `if ... else if`?  Is it relevant for one car (car1 for example) if the other car (car2 for example) isEmpty?

Comment: Do you expect only one car to be empty at a time?

Comment: @Vland: This isn't even basic C#, this is basic reason.  What would the control flow of such a construct even do?  There's no way to determine which "else" condition to use when the "if" fails.

Comment: this question is eligible to be deleted since it demonstrates very few research. I recommend to read some books or tutorials of programming fundamentals, you will get a better overview of all this logic stuff, and you will be happier. Otherwise you will get into hell as your applications grow

Comment: I've done research, I'm a fourth year computer science student. Granted at my university that doesn't mean a lot in terms of practice, but I had never encountered a situation like this before and googling it didn't bring up anything.

Comment: The right approach here is to get rid of your ten car variables and use an array to store them. That will make life a whole lot easier in the long term because you'll avoid exactly these kinds of situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for "when first car is not free use second one"?

```
if (Car1.isEmpty)
{
    Do stuff
}
else 
{
    Car1.EmptyOut();
    if (Car2.isEmpty)
    {
        Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
       Car2.EmptyOut()
    }
}
```

Note that if you have multiple "cars" using list of some sort and LINQ queries could make more sense. I.e.

```
var firstEmpty = cars.Where(car => car.IsEmpty).FirstOrDefault();
if (firstEmpty != null)
{
    // use empty car
}
else
{ 
    // no empty cars - recover and maybe retry...
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be an easier way as I have 10 cars to deal with lol, but thank you :) I guess I will just have to empty out each car in the next car's code.
[Edit: Just seeing your edit. That would probably work a lot better. I have a 'fairly simple' assignment but I have to copy paste the same 20-line bit 10 times for each car. I will look into it]

Comment: @Celestral - not sure what you mean - use array/list and iterate over them, `EmptyOut` every car till you find empty one (or find empty one first as in my sample)...

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. If you need to perform an action like this then it would be a good idea to use a loop

```
var carList = new List<car>();

for(var car in carList ) {
  if(car.isEmpty){
  //Do stuff
  } else {
    car.emptyOut();
  }
}
```

if you don't want to use a loop, for whatever reason, you can simply put a lot of if statements together

```
if(car1.isEmpty) {
  //Do stuff
} else {
  car1.emptyOut();
}

if(car2.isEmpty) {
  //Do stuff
} else {
  car2.emptyOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not allowed. Do this instead:

```
if (Car1.isEmpty)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
else 
{
    Car1.EmptyOut();

    if (Car2.isEmpty)
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
    else
    {
        Car2.EmptyOut();
    }
}
```

Since you have lots of cars, if you can enumerate their variable names, then you can use [reflection](http://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection). For example:

```
using System;

class Car
{
    public Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public bool isEmpty { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void EmptyOut() { }
}

static class Program
{
    public static Car Car0 = new Car("Car0");
    public static Car Car1 = new Car("Car1");
    public static Car Car2 = new Car("Car2");
    public static Car Car3 = new Car("Car3");
    public static Car Car4 = new Car("Car4");
    public static Car Car5 = new Car("Car5");
    public static Car Car6 = new Car("Car6");
    public static Car Car7 = new Car("Car7");
    public static Car Car8 = new Car("Car8");
    public static Car Car9 = new Car("Car9");

    static void Main()
    {
        var type = typeof(Program);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            var field = type.GetField("Car" + i);
            var temp = (Car)field.GetValue(null);

            if (temp.isEmpty)
            {
                // Do stuff.
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.EmptyOut();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not that OP wants

Comment: This is one of those cases where answering a question literally, while correct on facevalue, it seems much more likely that the OP just hasn't understood arrays yet. There really is no reason to ever use reflection for this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
if (Car1.isEmpty)
{
    //Do stuff
}
else 
{
    Car1.EmptyOut();
    if (Car2.isEmpty)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        Car2.EmptyOut()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

10 cars? If you've got more than a couple of cars, something like this should do you:

```
public bool Process( IEnumerable<Car> cars , Action<Car> process )
{
  bool success = false ;
  foreach( Car car in cars )
  {
    if ( car.IsEmpty )
    {
      process(car) ;
      success = true ;
      break ;
    }
    car.EmptyOut() ;
  }
  return success ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That s not possible in C# syntax, manage to use a Switch statement, or nested If Else statements